# Using discount code with recurring payments

Tags: discount, recurring, easy-digital-downloads

What happens if a discount amount is greater than one payment of a recurring payment product? For example, if a discount code of $25 is applied to a product costing $10 per month? Is the discount spread over the 3 first payments ($0, $0, $5, then $10...)? Or is it just applied to the first month ($0, $10...) and the remaining of the discount is lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the developer here:
https://easydigitaldownloads.com/blog/free-trial-support-added-recurring-payments/#comment-1060317

The short answer is that the discount is just applied to the first month.